# Lock and Update a records from DataSet in DB

Tags: database, dataset, locking, record

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter?view=netframework-4.8) **"Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter"**

> Pulling all of the table to the client also locks all of the rows on the server.

I didn't find any information (in Namespace: System.Data) regarding possibility to put lock on records (or group records) in DB, that was read to a DataSet (DataTable), which can affect all users of the DB, but not only those who will work with the database through my application.

Also From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters#using-updatedrowsource-to-map-values-to-a-dataset) **"Using UpdatedRowSource to Map Values to a DataSet"**

> The Update method resolves your changes back to the data source; however other clients may have modified data at the data source since the last time you filled the DataSet. To refresh your DataSet with current data, use the DataAdapter and Fill method. New rows will be added to the table, and updated information will be incorporated into existing rows. The Fill method determines whether a new row will be added or an existing row will be updated by examining the primary key values of the rows in the DataSet and the rows returned by the SelectCommand. If the Fill method encounters a primary key value for a row in the DataSet that matches a primary key value from a row in the results returned by the SelectCommand, it updates the existing row with the information from the row returned by the SelectCommand and sets the RowState of the existing row to Unchanged. If a row returned by the SelectCommand has a primary key value that does not match any of the primary key values of the rows in the DataSet, the Fill method adds a new row with a RowState of Unchanged.

If you we have modified copy records from DB (locally in-memory) in DataSet, and want to propogand these chanes to server, why we must refresh our local record? It can rejects all our changes.

I doesn't understand, in common, the strategy for organization modification a records in DB throught DataSet:

1. make local copy records (by  "Addapter.Fill(Dataset)")
2. change record (or records) locally (some contunies time) and wait when user click "Update", **when:**
3. save all modification in temp table?
4. reread records from DB (again by  "Addapter.Fill(Dataset)")?
5. compare records from temp table with updated Dataset?
6. And if any nothing is changed, quickly to update records in DB (by 
   "Addapter.Update(Dataset)")?

But also in that case, It's a possibly that someone would be more quickly than I (and can update "My records" between the my reread and my update?

Comment: I don't know why, I'm 2 days tryed to find answer on my question and only after I wrote here my question, I found some information on microsoft site (and others sites), It's a magic :(, sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Rereaded all articles about ADO.NET (from learn.microsoft.com), again, and found some additive information and can answer on own questions:

1) The reading records from DB to DataSet (by Addapter.Fill(Dataset) doesn’t put any lock on records in DB (the foregoing phrase from learn.microsoft.com “Pulling all of the table to …” isn’t correct).

2) “In a multiuser environment, there are two models for updating data in a database:  [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency?view=netframework-4.8) and pessimistic concurrency. The DataSet object is designed to encourage the use of optimistic concurrency (ONLY) for long-running activities, such as remoting data and interacting with data.”

A [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/local-transactions?view=netframework-4.8) (DbTransaction Class-derived types) which consists of a single command or a group of commands and which execute as a package, can put different types of locks on rows in tables in DB (DbTransaction.IsolationLevel Property).
Not correct use of transaction can very badly influence on work DB in multi-user env (the transactions must keep as short as possible).

3) When we talk regarding a locking records in DB, we must clear understood, what the aim of locking records and who it will be corresponds with logic work of our Application.

By example, we want made system for selling tickets for cinema (to simplify, for one movie and for one session only).

1. Application (which will run on multi-devices) must connect to DB and
   fill local DataSet, and show for users all available seats (all rows
   which have in special DB field SeatStatus = “FREE”).
2. After “selecting seat” user must press “Make Reservation” (MakeReservation()). Method MakeReservation() must use the ”Testing for Optimistic Concurrency Violations” (see  [example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency?view=netframework-4.8#optimistic-concurrency-example) it more elegant than my from first post) trying to change value of the field SeatStatus to “RESERVED”, in this time will use the “optimistic concurrency” – who will press first, that “receive seat”.
3. Who will “second” receive message “Sorry, place is reserved” and Update for current list of available seats (UpdateSeats()).
4. Also, UpdateSeats() must periodically run on all active devices (one
       per sec).
5. User who first pressed button, on next screen must entered
           credit card information and press “Pay” (PayTicket()).
6. Method PayTicket() must connect to Bank, check payment and change
       status SeatStatus to “OCCUPIED”, and this case (IMHO) more correct will use            a some transaction with “pessimistic
   concurrency”.
7. If User isn’t pressed “Pay” in some demanded time (5 min.) will
   return to previous
       screen and the field SeatStatus changed to “FREE”.

P.S>
Wellcome to all who knows more correct way to realize this task more correctly.